# Moment.js : Error ->UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, momentjs

I want to get if my timestamp now is equal or greater than , but im getting some errors

My code(with error):

```
   {...}
  exports.validaforgotpass = async (req, res) => {
     {...}
const results = await mysql.execute(query, [req.headers.email]);
    var newDateObj = moment(now).toDate();     
    newdate = moment(newDateObj).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    validDate = moment(results[0].codmailtime).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
         try {
            if (results.length < 1) {
              return res
                .status(401)
                .send({ user:{message: "Email não consta em nossa base de dados" }});
            }
          
            else if(req.headers.token = results[0].codmailtemp && newdate.isSameOrAfter(validDate)){ 
              return res.status(200).send({ user:{message:'Codigo correto',cod:results[0].codmailtemp}});
              }    
              else{
              return res.status(401).send({ user:{message:'Codigo incorreto',cod:results[0].codmailtemp}});
              }
            } catch {return res.status(500).send({ user:{message:messsage.error}});}
          } catch {return res.status(500).send({ user:{message: error.message}});}
        };
```

Someone knows why,and also how to fix it ?

Comment: You're trying to access `results[0].codmailtime` but you check `results.length` later. YOu need to check it before accessing an element at index 0

Comment: @Anatoly Im using just to set a variable to see if it was getting a value , and it is because before I put the `result[0]` in the conditional if and it also was returning me this error

Comment: Can you add console.log after each line where you are  using `moment` to see what line is causing an error

Comment: @Anatoly thanks for the attention brah , but i wasnt declaring the now function , Im just a dumb junior sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't putting my variable as date object.
I corrected my code as below and it's running well.

```
  var now = new Date();
    const moment= require('moment') 
try{
    newdate = moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    validDate = moment(results[0].codmailtime).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    console.log(validDate > newdate)
  }catch{
    {return res.status(500).send({ user:{message: error.message}});}
    }
    try {
    if (results.length < 1) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .send({ user:{message: "Email não consta em nossa base de dados" }});
    }
    else if(req.headers.tok
```